# Pidfile for clickhouse-server is missing

Tags: clickhouse

I'm working on a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 VM.

With following steps I have installed ClickHouse.

```
echo "deb http://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/deb/stable/ main/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/clickhouse.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv E0C56BD4
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y clickhouse-server clickhouse-client
```

Then I start ClickHouse like this.

```
sudo clickhouse-server --config-file=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
```

And I also tried to  specify the pidfile path.

```
sudo clickhouse-server --config-file=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml --pid-file=/var/run/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.pid
```

ClickHouse documentation says that the pidfile should be at `/var/run/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.pid`, but I can't find it.
Running `sudo find / -name clickhouse*.pid` shows that there is no pidfile for clickhouse.

Is there something I'm missing? Do I have to change the configuration?

How can I get the pid of the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, ClickHouse doesn't generate a pid file. Instead, it has a `status` file under the root of the data directory which contains the pid value.

```
❯ cat data/status
PID: 23465
Started at: 2018-12-02 18:47:10
Revision: 54409
```